# Good workaround for pgfmath/tikz definition of inverse cosine?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I wanted to draw a graph of y = arccosine(x) and saw in the Tikz documentation the function `acos` which claims to do this but returns a result in the range [-90,90] (degrees). I was surprised by this since cos(x) is not one-to-one over the domain [-90,90], and most conventional definitions would put the range of `acos` as [0,180].

The fact that the function defined is not inverse cosine can be verified by the following minimal working example, in which pgf claims that the inverse cosine of -1 is 0:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\begin{document}
Inverse cosine of $-1$ is apparently \pgfmathparse{acos(-1)} \pgfmathresult 
\end{document}
```

I'm not sure whether to count this as a bug (since the documentation explicitly states that it will work in this way) but is there a good workaround to easily get the actual inverse cosine function in pgfmath/tikz?

Comment: The current version of PGF (v2.1) behaves correctly. It is strongly recommended to update to this version (not just for the `acos` behaviour).

Comment: @Jake, you are right, and in fact my minimal example doesn't even compile any more with the updated version of PGF. I ended up trying to update tikz from miktex 2.7, which is no longer supported, necessitating an upgrade to miktex 2.9, which doesn't seem as good (can't get all latex packages downloaded locally first), necessitating a crossgrade to texlive 2010, which now works. Possibly not worth it for this small bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was [fixed in revision 1.3 of `pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex`](http://pgf.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pgf/pgf/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex?view=diff&r1=text&tr1=1.3&r2=text&tr2=1.2&diff_format=h), dated 2009-01-22.

It is strongly recommended to upgrade to the current version of PGF (v 2.1), which includes this file.

If you do not want to update, you can just declare the fixed functions in your document by including the following code chunk in your preamble. You can then access the corrected functions using `newasin` and `newacos`.

```
\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{newasin}{1}{%
    \begingroup%
        \expandafter\pgfmath@x#1pt\relax%
        \pgfmath@xa\pgfmath@x%
        \ifdim\pgfmath@x<0pt\relax%
            \pgfmath@x-\pgfmath@x%
        \fi%
        \pgfmath@x1000\pgfmath@x%
        \afterassignment\pgfmath@gobbletilpgfmath@%
        \expandafter\c@pgfmath@counta\the\pgfmath@x\relax\pgfmath@%
        \pgfmath@x-\csname pgfmath@acos@\the\c@pgfmath@counta\endcsname pt\relax%
        \advance\pgfmath@x90pt\relax%
        \ifdim\pgfmath@xa<0pt\relax%
            \pgfmath@x-\pgfmath@x%
        \fi%
        \pgfmath@returnone\pgfmath@x%
    \endgroup%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{newacos}{1}{%
    \begingroup%
        \expandafter\pgfmath@x#1pt\relax%
        \pgfmath@xa\pgfmath@x%
        \ifdim\pgfmath@x<0pt\relax%
            \pgfmath@x-\pgfmath@x%
        \fi%
        \pgfmath@x1000\pgfmath@x%
        \afterassignment\pgfmath@gobbletilpgfmath@%
        \expandafter\c@pgfmath@counta\the\pgfmath@x\relax\pgfmath@%
        \expandafter\pgfmath@x\csname pgfmath@acos@\the\c@pgfmath@counta\endcsname pt\relax%
        \ifdim\pgfmath@xa<0pt\relax%
            \pgfmath@x-\pgfmath@x%
            \advance\pgfmath@x by180pt\relax%
        \fi%
        \pgfmath@returnone\pgfmath@x%
    \endgroup%
}
```

Comment: I haven't checked whether your code sample works, preferring instead just to upgrade my pgf/tikz.

Comment: I actually checked it and get this error:  ! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \pgfmath@acos@2164 
l.142 ...  \pgfmathsetmacro\phiang{newacos(\dotr)}
                                                  
? 
Any ideas?